# Retornando um resultado só, como retornar todos?

Tags: php, soap, php-7

Porfavor alguem me ajuda, preciso retornar todos os dados.. mais ele só retorna o primeiro
como faço para retornar todos os resultados , o código que estou usando é este

```
try {
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

$wsdlUrl = 'xxx';

$soapClientOptions = array(
    "login"      => "xxxx",
    "password"  => "xxxx",
    "stream_context" => $context,
    "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapClientOptions);

echo $status =  (string) simplexml_load_string(

$client->RealizarConsultaSQL
([
  'codSentenca'   => 'xxxx',
  'codColigada'   => 'xxxx',
  'codSistema'    => 'xxxx',
  'parameters'    => 'xxxx'
])
->RealizarConsultaSQLResult)->Resultado->xxx;

}
catch(Exception $e) {
  //  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o retorno pelo SOAPUI, olha como ele retorna todos os resultados!
mais no código acima ele só aparece o primeiro assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você apenas deu um `echo`; se são vários registros você não deveria ter um laço de repetição?

Comment: Boa tarde! nao estou conseguindo fazer esse laço ja tentei de tudo! pode me ajudar.. só falta isso para eu terminar, me ajudem!

Comment: Já experimentou dar um `var_dump` no objeto que é resultado do `simplexml_load_string`? Seria bom você fazer isso e [edit] sua pergunta pra adicionar este resultado. Dessa maneira seu problema seria visto rapidamente pela comunidade e seria resolvido rapidamente.

Comment: boa tarde fernando, consegui resolver o problema era apenas retirar 

->Resultado->xxx; e agora ta trazendo todos os resultados!

print_r($arr = json_encode($status_CODIGO , 1));

agora como eu trato isso no meu JS? queria trazer o resultado para um select dentro do meu html